# How to solve change contents of variables having values from call by reference facility in Java?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I had written the following code as follows:

```java
class Numbers
{

    int temp,a1,b1;

    void swapping(){
        temp = a1;
        a1 = b1;
        b1 = temp;
        System.out.println("In numbers class value of a after swapping ="+a1 + " and that of b=" + b1);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Swap{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=2;
        int b=3;
        System.out.println("In swapping class value of a before swapping ="+a + " and that of b=" + b);

        Numbers num = new Numbers();        

        num.a1= a;
        num.b1= b;
        num.swapping();
        System.out.println("In swapping class value of a after swapping ="+a + " and that of b=" + b);
    }

}
```

Now the values of a1 and b1 in void swapping() are unchanged as per the dummy println statement just after the swapping operation is implemented on both a1 and b1 . This is the same as the values printed in the main function just before the swapping function was called . However the println statement in the main function after the function call shows the swapped values . Suppose instead of the swapped values some garbage value is stored due to some unforeseen abnormalities in Java compiler , then how to change that to whatever is desired?

Comment: Are you saying you see the "after swapping" print statement showing `a = 3` and `b = 2`? Because that's not possible in Java.

Comment: OP, Java, unline C/C++ or virtually any other language, prohibits the editing of a variable outside its declaration block. It is essentially passing, for the lack of a better term, an `int*` and collecting it in an `int*`. What you'll have to do if you have to swap using a function, is add it to a Pair or a List and then modify the list inside the function.

Comment: In your case, you are not swapping a or b, but a1 and b1. They being swapped in the same "scope", the swap works.

Comment: "Suppose instead of the swapped values some garbage value is stored due to some unforeseen abnormalities in Java compiler , then how to change that to whatever is desired?" I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Class names start with uppercase letter in Java conventions. I fixed yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is understanding that Java has two parallel [type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system):

- primitives (for faster execution, least memory used, similarity to [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language))
- classes & objects (for benefits of [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming))

In your code:

```
num.a1 = a;
```

… you are copying the quantity of two from `a`, and putting that quantity into `a1`. After that statement executes, `a` and `a1` are independent. They are two separate numbers, two separate values, without knowledge of one another. This is because they are primitives.

In your code:

```
Numbers num = new Numbers();
```

… you switched to the OOP type system. Here you instantiated an `Numbers` object, which means you grabbed a piece of memory somewhere else, carved out room in that memory for the three primitives defined in that class. You also carved out room for a reference to implementation of the method named `swapping` that lives inside the class definition.

A reference (or link, or pointer) was made from that instantiated `Numbers` object floating around in memory to your local variable named `num`.

When you called the `swapping` method, that code worked on the `a1` and `b1` primitive values stored *within* your object. That code knows nothing about the `a` and `b` variables that live outside the object, that live locally within the `main` method only.

So after the `swapping` code finishes, you can think of memory in your [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) as looking like this diagram. After swapping, the `a` and `b` variables remain in their original condition, untouched. Only the `a1` and `b1` variables (and `temp`) were touched.

[image: digram of main method distinct from object]

So code in separate scopes *can* share references to the same object. But code in separate scopes *cannot* share the very same primitive variable, they can only get a copy of the other's primitive variable's value.

Comment: Thank you for opening my eye . Just retrieving back the addresses of the swapped values showed the change in println statement of the main function.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("In swapping class value of a after swapping ="+a + " and that of b=" + b);
```

You are just printing a and b variables here. Because there is no re-assignment for a and b anywhere in `swap` class. Change your code to print `num.a1` and `num.b1` and you should see the values changed for `num` object